# How to convert multi dimensional json to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I'm stuck, I have googled and searched here on the stack.

First, I create a JS obj:

```
var formData = {};

//LOOP THREW TABLE ROWS
$("tr.element_row").each(function(index, element){

     var $this = $(this);
     var $inputs = $this.find("input.formData");

     formData[index] = {};

      //LOOP THREW INPUTS
      $.each($inputs, function(n, e){
         //this is each input in this tr

         if( $(this).attr('name') == 'el' ){
             formData[index]['el'] = $(this).val();
         } ...
```

Then I convert it with JSON stringify:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);

//RESULT (console.log(myJSON))
{"0":{"obj":"1234","el":"1","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"1":{"obj":"1234","el":"2","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"2":....
```

Then I send it with ajax to PHP:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/add_elementdata.php',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: myJSON,
```

Then i do a `var_dump($_POST)`

```
//RESULT
array(1) {
["{"0": {"obj":"1234","el":"1","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"1":{"obj":"1234","el":"2","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"2":{"obj":"1234","el":"3","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"3":{"obj":"1234","el":"4","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"},"4":{"obj":"1234","el":"5","lit":"1","height":"","type":"","length":"","width":"","weight_kg":"","proj":"BC"}}"]=> string(0) ""}
```

Then I want to create a multidimensional array of this.. array..string..

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST);
or
$arr = json_decode($_POST, true);
echo $arr;
```

But `$arr` returns empty. why?

Comment: `var_dump($arr);` not echo its an std object

Comment: @Rahul Well, if it had worked it had sad "array" but now echo says nothing and var_dump say "null"

Comment: Try  data: {'myJSON': myJSON} instead of  data: myJSON. And on server end print it by print_r($_POST)

Comment: $_POST returns array of all post vars. Try `json_decode($_POST[0]);` to only get the first array.

Comment: If you are already creating a json, does it make sense to write `var myJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);` again? Try commenting this line

Comment: also you should be sending `data: {'myJSON':myJSON}` then getting it with `$_POST['myJSON']`

Comment: Yes, Miro's advice should be followed too.

Comment: @Rahul I have already tryed this, but this wont make any difference.. it will not create a multidimensional array in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed `data: myJSON,`, it means that you've passed variable (your JSON string) with empty value. It was shown in `var_dump()` - `["json" => '']`. So, you can use it in PHP in the next way:

```
 foreach($_POST as $data=>$emptyVal){
   // here you can add any checking stuff
    $arr = json_decode($data,true) ;
 }

print_r($arr);
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/Y42OG)

But, you need just to change `data: myJSON,` on, for example, `data: {jsonn : myJSON},`. And now you will be able to use it in PHP as `$_POST['jsonn']`:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['jsonn'],true) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're sending an ajax request via jQuery and you want to send FormData you don't need to use JSON.stringify on this FormData.

and also when you're sending file the content-type must be multipart/form-data.
so use something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(errResponse) {
        console.log(errResponse);
    }
});
```

Comment: Before i went with the solution to create a string, i was sending a object. But it did not work. The object was cut after 111 nestled indexes.. i send 199.. but only 111 reccived to the php file

Comment: Did you try with serialize form data?

Comment: I also wonder if `JSON.stringify()` is necessary, but 1) OP is not using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData); 2) OP is not sending files. 3) `contentType: false`?  What happened to the `multipart/form-data` recommendation?

Comment: Setting processData to false (prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string), Setting the contentType to false (This is needed because otherwise, jQuery will set it incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: {data: myJSON},
});`